# How do I draw an ellipse with arbitrary orientation pixel by pixel?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, shapes, ellipse

I have to draw an ellipse of arbitrary size and orientation pixel by pixel.  It seems pretty easy to draw an ellipse whose major and minor axes align with the x and y axes, but rotating the ellipse by an arbitrary angle seems trickier.  Initially I though it might work to draw the unrotated ellipse and apply a rotation matrix to each point, but it seems as though that could cause errors do to rounding, and I need rather high precision.

Is my suspicion about this method correct?  How could I accomplish this task more precisely?

I'm programming in C++ (although that shouldn't really matter since this is a more algorithm-oriented question).

Edit: as David pointed out, I guess I may really be wondering how to do pixel interpolation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
x = X cos(a) - Y sin(a)
y = Y cos(a) + X sin(a)
```

Where `a` is the angle of anticlockwise rotation, `(x, y)` are the new coordinates, and `(X, Y)` are the old.

You should use floats to preserve precision. Just go through every point, apply the transformation, and voilà.

Edit: after some searching, here's some code from Microsoft: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/awf/graphics/bres-ellipse.html that draws rastered conic sections.

Comment: I believe this runs the usual risk with "forward" transformations: that the aliasing will cause you to "skip" pixels in the transformed coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I've been looking for a different method.  Are there any good ways to deal with aliasing?

Comment: Yeah, I mean, it all depends on what library you use to do your drawing. But aliasing will screw up any type of rotation. Your question should be "how do I do pixel interpolation?" :)

Comment: @amc: I read working solution once, but it's in a book somewhere... I'll dig it up and post it if I find time and no one eats me to it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help.  At least now I know what to search for. :D

Comment: Interpolation is extremely general, but is not the only solution, and can be slow by comparison to other methods. The classic example of how to *not* have to interpolate are the Bresenham methods for lines and circles. I assume a similar technique exist for this case...

Comment: Added a link to some fun code by MS, it's pretty verbose so it should be easy to follow :}

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 4):

Bresenham (famous for his [line drawing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm)) also has an algorithm for drawing an ellipse. You can try to google *[bresenham ellipse](http://www.google.com/search?q=bresenham+ellipse)*.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Bresenham method of drawing axis-aligned ellipses, but apply a shear to the drawn ellipse.  You will also need to modify the lengths of the axes. [A sheared ellipse is also an ellipse.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qo8bwtvc7ohij00/EllipseShear.pdf?dl=0) This method preserves the Bresenham advantage of drawing filled ellipses using horizontal line segments.  What you need in order to do this is the function which maps a specification of an ellipse in terms of axes and rotation into a different set of axes and a shear.  A solution is available online at http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/50039326/ with a discussion about the method and a [description of the math involved](https://www.dropbox.com/s/su4bkjepexmwh1w/EllipseTransform.pdf?dl=0) at http://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/94194/

The mapping was discovered by Nathan Dinsmore (user nXIII at the [MIT Scratch site](http://scratch.mit.edu/))

Comment: This is amazing. Should be the top answer as it's a new, better, solution to an old question.

Comment: Without a doubt this is the right answer. But why in the world was this implemented in scratch :/

Comment: There's javascript code at the foot of http://g6auc.me.uk/ellipses/index.html which may be more accessible.